# display selected thumbnail for initial subview in a scrollview

Tags: ios, indexing, scrollview, collectionview

Trying to get the selected image from an array of images in a collection view to be the initial subview in a scrollview. Right now the scrollView loads the first image from the array, no matter which image is tapped on in the collection view. Please give some advice or websites with information on how to achieve this. Thanks!

```
 for (int i = 0; i < self.album.count; i++) {
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

    UIImageView *subview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    subview.image = [self.album objectAtIndex:i];

    [self.scrollView addSubview:subview];
}

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * self.album.count, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of creating scrollview add below line

```
self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * self.selectedImage, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
```

where `self.selectedImage` is the index of the image in the array

PD: Sorry for my english.